# How to add featured image use HTML

Tags: images

I'm starter of Wordpress.
And I really want to know how to add featured image of post using HTML.

[image]
I know there is default function to add featured image on sidebar.
But on that, I can only add images that already exist on my media.
But I want to add by HTML code.
That code is

```
<a href="https://~~~" ></a><img src="https://~~~" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
```

I want to add that code to featured image. 
Please help me.
I struggle for 2days to solve this...

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, that's not how the featured image works. WordPress just stores the image ID in this feature. If you want to include the same image-with-a-link on all posts, you could instead create a child theme and modify the `single.php` file (for Posts) or `page.php` (for Pages), and include the HTML code there.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Can I ask is it too hard to beginer that create a child theme and add code on it?

Comment: It's fairly easy. You basically need to create a `style.css` file that includes comments that tell WordPress "This is a child theme, and the parent theme is ...(fill in the blank)". Then the biggest part of the work is finding the right file to make your change in. See https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ to get started